# My application fails to read data from IBM DB2 when deployed on server, but succeed from my development pc

Tags: asp.net, database, db2

My application fails to make a connection with the DB2 Database when I deploy it to the server. It works fine on my local development machine.

`con.open()` throw the following exception:

> SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 10, tokens 0.0.0, 11.1.0, Process Owner: IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.5 Classic

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Is the account that runs IIS on the server a member of either the DB2ADMNS group or DB2USERS group on that server?

Comment: Also, remote-desktop to the server running the app-server, and once there verify you can make a connection to the Db2 database from the command-line (db2cmd.exe) using the same credentials used in your application.

Comment: I have added the admin user and the regular user of the remote server to the above mentioned user groups.

Now in regards to making the connection from DB2 database form cmd, I am not sure how that is done, are you aware of any guide i can read on? I am also doing my research. Thank you

Comment: You may need to restart IIS after adding the account that runs IIS to the specified groups.  You have to be able to compare the working-environment to the failing-environment to solve your problem.   If you don't know how to use the db2cmd.exe command line then check if your database appears in odbcad32 as either a system-dsn or a user-dsn and try connecting from there. You can also ask a colleague (whoever set up the Db2 connection on the app-server) or follow IBM's online documentation.

Comment: I checked the odbcad32 in both my machine and the remote server, but did not find the database name in either of them. I am using a server URL with port to connect to the database on my development machine.